# UIView.hidden doesn't work immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView and UIView (see blow). When I call `hiddenLoadingView` at somewhere, the UIView is still showing, then dismiss after 10-20 seconds, why?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ....
    self.tableView = [[[UITableView alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

    self.loadingView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.view addSubview:self.loadingView];
}

- (void)hiddenLoadingView {
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.loadingView.hidden]);
    [self.loadingView setHidden:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.loadingView.hidden]);
}
```

Comment: Be sure to call `hiddenLoadingView` from the main thread. Sounds like you might be calling it from the completion block of some asynchronous method.

Comment: that's this... thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to call hiddenLoadingView from the main thread. Sounds like you might be calling it from the completion block of some asynchronous method.

Comment: Exactly Correct ..as i have a complex set of UITableViewCell and Have Conditionally stuff to show and hide ...Since the request is of type asynchronous so elements are not hiding properly ..doing the same in Main thread did the trick........

Answer (score 0):

you have to call UI changes From main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
// do UI related work here
})
```